# Move files based on directory name (Linux / Debian / #!)

Tags: linux, file, sorting, subdirectory

**Question:**

How do I move files from many sub-directories with the same name to a single directory of that name. All files in multiple directories named X should get moved together into one directory named X.

**Example file structure:**

(The real structure is 200-300 directories at the level I've marked as 1, 2, 3, etc., with varying numbers of directories below that.)

(Note all labels like Group _ are just that--labels. The actual names are irregular.)

- Disk

  - 1

    - Library

      - Music

        - Group A

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
        - Group B

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
  - 2

    - Library

      - Music

        - Group B

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
        - Group C

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
  - 3

    - Library

      - Music

        - Group C

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
        - Group D

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files

The goal is to have files in various sub-directories with name "Group X" moved into a **single** directory with name "Group X", like so:

- Disk

  - 1

    - Library

      - Music

        - Group A

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
        - Group B

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
        - Group C

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
          - Files
        - Group D

          - Files
          - Files
          - Files

Thanks!

Comment: You could run into trouble if this will result in a large number (depending on a kernel parameter the name of which escapes me now) in a single directory.  You could run out of inodes.  Also there could be performance problems.

Comment: What's wrong with `cp -r /disk2/Library /disk3/Library /disk1`?

Comment: I only need to process ~2000-3000 files and roughly 1/10 as many folders. (I think this answers comment 2 too!)

Comment: Let me provide some color that might help ppl sink their teeth into this: The files are mp3s. They used to be in about 200 directories with names based on "Artist - Album," but the filesystem got messed up so that some "Artist - Album" folders got split so that only a portion of the mp3s are inside, with the remaining portion in a folder of the same name in an adjacent directory. Add to this the fact that they were all in parent directories sorted by genre, which similarly were split into multiple adjacent like-named directories.

Comment: So I want to restore the proper order of mp3 files in their correctly named directories and genre parent directories. Whew! Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like:

```
dest="Group A"
find -type f | 
grep $dest | 
while read filename
do     
    echo mv $filename ${dest}/$(basename $filename)
done
```

Comment: I can't do anything based on filename, only directory name. Also there are thousands of "Group X" files that need to be re-sorted so anything based on unique directory names like Group A isn't going to be feasible. Can this be modified to serve this purpose? I'm afraid I don't understand much of what you've written. Thank you!

Comment: "Group X" are directories right? You could do something like `for dest in find -type d | grep "Group"`, and put everything in that loop.

Comment: Sorry hendry, I'm using the "Group _" label as a placeholder. The names are actually not regular beyond what I describe in my comments on the original question.

Comment: So you can't grep Group? Maybe you can tell find to find say directories of depth 3?

Comment: Thanks for your help again! I don't think grep will help here. I think we must start with the lowest sub-directory and ask, are there any directories in the filestructure with the same name? Yes? Move contained files to that directory. Delete empty directory. Move to next directory. Ask again, are there any directories with the same name? Yes? Move files. Delete empty. Once it runs out of directories at a given level, it should move to the parent level of directories and perform the same find/move/delete empty, with the exception that sub-directories would now have to move as well...